# Differences between numpy and matlab Dot Product / Matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I found on the matlab homepage the following example (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) that the result of the dot product is 
[ 6,15]
 [10,20]
Tha is different to my result in numpy. Is this an issue?

```
    In [79]: W1 * W2
Out[79]:
array([[  3.,   0.],
       [  3.,  20.]])

In [80]: W1
Out[80]:
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])

In [81]: W2
Out[81]:
array([[ 3.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  5.]])

In [82]: np.dot(W1,W2)
Out[82]:
array([[  5.,  10.],
       [ 13.,  20.]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've taken wrong array from that link, specifically `W1`

It should be

```
In [41]: W1
Out[41]:
array([[ 1.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  4.]])
```

`W2` as have it

```
In [42]: W2
Out[42]:
array([[ 3.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  5.]])

In [43]: np.dot(W1, W2)
Out[43]:
array([[  6.,  15.],
       [ 10.,  20.]])

In [44]: W1*W2
Out[44]:
array([[  3.,   0.],
       [  2.,  20.]])
```

Now, outputs match with Matlab outputs.

Answer (score 0):

When you do W1 * W2 you use the hadamard product, which is the elementwise product while the np.dot is the matrix multiplication.